# What is the best USB file system format for linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I want to format a 2TB USB which I plan use for storing media (some of which may go over 10+GB). As I don't plan on using it on any other system aside from Linux-based system I don't really care about compatibility. So, as mentioned in the title, what is the best file system format (NTFS, FAT32, exFAT etc...) I can go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about compatibility, I recommend using `Ext4`, it is especially developed for linux.

Comment: Windows 10 will be able to mount ext4 before very long using WSL2.

Comment: Make sure to check my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1346350/is-there-a-way-to-make-ext-filesystems-use-less-space-for-themselves-in-linux) if you go with `Ext4`. On an external HDD you will most likely not want/need root-reserved space but rather have more space available for your files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for late reply. Guess I will go with that.

Comment: I'd use [F2FS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS): it has been specially designed for flash storage.